# Seg fault when using scanf to define the size

Tags: arrays, c, segmentation-fault, scanf, structure

I have a strange issue with my code :
I have a function generating a dynamic array of struct and only takes an int size as parameter.

It's work well until i try to add just a scanf("d";&size); to choose the size of my array, can't understand why i get a seg fault.

Note : There is no issue with compilation if i remove the line containing scanf

```
pokemon_t * createPkmDatabase( int taille){
  printf("taille %d",taille);
  pokemon_t *tableau=malloc(sizeof(pokemon_t)*taille);
  ...
  ...
}
```

```
int main(){
/*"taille" means size in french */
    int taille=5;
    printf("Saisir taille : "); 
    scanf("%d",&taille); /* <-- BREAKS EVERYTHING */
    printf("valeur de taille : %d\n ",taille);
    pokemon_t *database=createPkmDatabase(taille);
}
```

I don't get why changing the value of "taille" with a simple scanf change anything the value.

It doesn't even seems to enter in the function bc it doesn't even print the value of the size

Comment: Description has `scanf("d";&size);`.  Code has `scanf("%d",&taille);`.  Is the true code using `"d"` or `"%d"`?

Answer (score 1):

There are no errors in the code shown.

Some remarks:

1. Use the correct type for sizes (`size_t`)
2. Always check the result of `scanf` and `malloc`

```
typedef struct {
    int x,y,z;
}pokemon_t; 

pokemon_t * createPkmDatabase(size_t taille){
  printf("taille %d",taille);
  pokemon_t *tableau=malloc(sizeof(*tableau)*taille);
  return tableau;
}

int main(){
/*"taille" means size in french */
    size_t taille;
    printf("Saisir taille : "); 
    if(scanf("%zu",&taille) == 1)
    { 
        printf("valeur de taille : %zu\n ",taille);
        pokemon_t *database=createPkmDatabase(taille);
        if(database)
        {
            printf("\nAllocation OK\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nAllocation FAILED\n");
        }
        free(database);
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ExjYe5G94